# The EdiReceive and SendEdi pipelines are missing from my BizTalk 2006 R2 application

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-deployment

I am still learning BizTalk and EDI. When I originally started at my current company I inherited my predecessor's computer, so a lot of configuration was already in place. I recently got a new laptop, and have almost finished configuring the new development environment. There was no documentation on how to setup a dev environment before I got here (I have created such a document which has gotten rather lengthy).

The last piece I can't seem to figure out is the EdiRecieve and SendEdi ports. They are on my old dev environment but they do not appear on my new one. From what I have been able to turn up Google dumpster diving, they exist in the Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiPipelines but do not appear to be installed by default. My question is how do I get these in my primary BizTalk application I use for development?

Another sideline, there is a BizTalk EDI Application that is apparently installed by default that does have the pipelines I am looking for. Do I need to reference that application or something somehow?

I tried GAC'ing the dlls, but that hasn't seemed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the EDI application. To do this follow the steps below (taken from  MSDN( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226366(BTS.10).aspx))

1. In the BizTalk Server Administration Console, under the Applications node, right-click the application that you want to use for EDI, such as BizTalk Application 1. Point to Add, and then click References.
2. Select BizTalk EDI Application, and then click OK.

You can also use the EDI components that make up the pipelines (e.g. the EDIDissambler) in your own custom pipelines, you are not limited to just the out of the box pipelines - this is a very handy thing to know that it took me a while to realise.